# Search button not working, it said that no database selected, how to fix this?

Tags: mysql

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ICT_Assigment_3
{
    public partial class search : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=password");
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable dbdataset;

        public search()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valueToSearch = search_box.Text.ToString();
            searchData(valueToSearch);
        }

        private void search_box_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void search_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchData("");

        }

        public void searchData(string valueToSearch)
        {


            string query = "SELECT * FROM library WHERE add_update('BookName','Publisher','Category','Edition','Year','Location')LIKE'%"+search_box+"%'";
            command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dbdataset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset;



        }
    }
}
```

I am new to c#, can someone help me to fix it. I want to search my database, my database have BookName,Publisher, Category,Edition,Year,Location.
I wan to search for all thing, like if i have a book name The Light, R.R is the publisher, fiction category, first edition, 2002 for year and K105 for location in my library.
When i type Light in the text box, it should filter out The Light,R.R....
When i type R.R, it also should show the light, R.R...
Same as category, year, location etc.
i also wan show error if there is no the book in my library
And it is show in data grid view.

Comment: `it said that no database selected, how to fix this?` ... selecting a database might help.  In addition, though unrelated, you should not be building your query string through concatenation, because you could get attacked by SQL injection.

Comment: Indeed your code does connect to the database server, but it does not select a specific database within that server.

Comment: how to i select it?

Comment: Your connection string needs to specify a Database parameter, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which database to use when establish a connection by adding "database" parameter on your connection string. So, your connection string has to be something like this:

```
"server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=password;database=your_database"
```

Please see [MySQL Connector .NET documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html)

Or, you can specify which database to use directly from your query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_database.library 
WHERE add_update('BookName','Publisher','Category','Edition','Year','Location')
LIKE'%"+search_box+"%'"
```